# Use the set method directly or loop over the arrayList to set the data

Tags: java

Can someone explain me why the childern node of the nextNode are deleted after clearing the `cache.clear();` if I set the the cache conetent arrayList by invoking:

```
 child1.setNext(cache);
```

and they are not being deleted if I adding them with the for loop `child1.next.add(cacheNode);`

```
                    for (TrieNode cacheNode : cache) {
                        child1.next.add(cacheNode);

                    }
```

The work below works but I just want to understand Why can not I use `child1.setNext(cache);`?

**Code:**

```
                    ArrayList<TrieNode> cache = new ArrayList<TrieNode>();
                    if (nextNode.getNext() != null
                            && !nextNode.getNext().isEmpty()) {
                        for (TrieNode nextNodeChildern : nextNode.getNext()) {
                            cache.add(nextNodeChildern);

                        }
                        nextNode.setEdge(communsubString);
                        nextNode.getNext().clear();

                        TrieNode child1 = new TrieNode(substringSplit1);
                        //child1.setNext(cache);
                        for (TrieNode cacheNode : cache) {
                            child1.next.add(cacheNode);

                        }
                        nextNode.next.add(child1);
                        cache.clear();

                        TrieNode child2 = new TrieNode(substringSplit2);
                        child2.setWord(true);
                        nextNode.next.add(child2);

                    }
```

**TrieNode class:**

```
class TrieNode {

ArrayList<TrieNode> next = new ArrayList<TrieNode>();
String edge;
boolean isWord;

// To create normal node.
TrieNode(String edge) {
    this.edge = edge;

}

// To create the root node.
TrieNode() {
    this.edge = "";

}

public ArrayList<TrieNode> getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(ArrayList<TrieNode> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String getEdge() {
    return edge;
}

public void setEdge(String edge) {
    this.edge = edge;
}

public boolean isWord() {
    return isWord;
}

public void setWord(boolean isWord) {
    this.isWord = isWord;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `cache` to `setNext` you're passing a reference to the `cache` list, i.e. the List in your node and the List in your main code points to the same List in memory.  When you call `clear` you're emptying out that list, which is being used by your node.

You need to use a copy of the list for your node by either taking a copy outside or inside the node class, so something like this would work:

```
public void setNext(ArrayList<TrieNode> next) {
    this.next = new ArrayList<>(next);
}
```

This will create a new `ArrayList` inside the node and copy all the elements from `next` into it.